# C# concatenate string for serial send

Tags: c#, serial-port, string-concatenation

I have a sensor connected through serial port to a Windows PC and programming in C#.
Commands have to be terminated with `"\r"` for them to be interpreted by the sensor.
When I do:

```
string cmd = "COMMAND\r";
serialPort.send(cmd);
```

I get an immediate response.

But if I do:

```
string cmd = "COMMAND" + "\r";
serialPort.send(cmd);
```

I'm getting no response. I've checked and the `char[]` representation of both strings seems to be the same.

What am I missing?

Solved: The above code works. The problem was elsewhere. Sigh.

Comment: Did you copy/pasted theses commands? What's the real input (instead of `COMMAND`)?

Comment: The string construction is not the cause of your problem. Look elsewhere (is it just that the first command works but the second doesn't?)

Comment: Compare the output of `cmd.GetHashCode()`. If they're not the same, you're lucky

Comment: You're rght. It's something else. I'm trying to condense it into the smallest function that shows the problem. Be right back.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases are correct. The problem you have, I am almost sure, depends on programming SerialPort object. 
It is not always enough just to request `BytesToRead` and then "Read" from the port. From lesson learned the more reliable solution is to have a `Port Listenning` task that permanently reads out the port output, append the output to some buffer, analyses the buffer content and then, in case of particular state detection, emmits and particular condition event.

The most obvious idea about implementation of a delay between *send to* port and *read from* the port will work unstable and slow.

One more advice about troubleshouting the port issue is to use a sniffer to see the real output of the port.

Also I would recommend to use `Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` and `Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` command for port IO

Answer (score 0):

The problem was kind of dumb. In my function I was getting the first part of the string, then creating a second string with the "\r" terminator. But I was still sending the first one instead of the modified one.

```
private string sendCommand(string cmd)
    {
        string command = cmd + "\r";
        string response = "";
        try
        {
            sp.Write(cmd);     //There's my problem!
            response = sp.ReadTo("\r");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {   
            Debug.WriteLine("Send Command: " + cmd + " : " + e.Message);
        }
        return response;
    }
```